# wso2am 1.9.0 path parameters issue

Tags: wso2-api-manager, publisher, path-parameter

Actually i'm working with WSO2 Api Manager 1.9.0. I've published an API with a ressource with the following url template:
/web/v1.2/test/{id}?user=12345

now when i try to request this resources it issue a not found matching resource exception.

any one have a solution for my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i've found solutions to my issue.

if you want to publish a ressource with path parameter like this one:
/web/v1.2/test/{id} you'll not have a problem
but if you want to publish a ressource like
/web/v1.2/test/{id}?user=12345 you should add a "/" after the path parameter to separate between the path param and the query param.